# Pyspark - replace values in column with dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I'm avoiding repeating the `.when` function 12 times, so I thought about a dictionary. I don't know if it's a limitation of the Spark function or a logic error. Does the function allow this concatenation?

```
months = {'1': 'Jan', '2': 'Feb', '3': 'Mar', '4': 'Apr', '5': 'May', '6': 'Jun',
         '7': 'Jul', '8': 'Aug', '9': 'Sep', '10':'Oct', '11': 'Nov', '12':'Dec'}

for num, month in months.items():
    custoDF1 = custoDF.\
    withColumn("Month", 
               when(col("Nummes") == num, month)
               .otherwise(month))   
custoDF1.select(col('Nummes').alias('NumMonth'), 'month').distinct().orderBy("NumMonth").show(200)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the sample data of custoDF along with the output of the custoDF? It could be minimum records just to verify how the data is there in the dataframe.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to reduce this code by iterating through the dictionary.

`
custoDF1 = custoDF.withColumn("Month", 
                                  when(col("Nummes") == "1","Jan")
                                 .when(col("Nummes") == "2","Feb")
                                 .when(col("Nummes") == "3","Mar")                                                                 
                                 .otherwise(lit("n\a")))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html) method of the DataFrame class:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

months = {'1': 'Jan', '2': 'Feb', '3': 'Mar', '4': 'Apr', '5': 'May', '6': 'Jun',
          '7': 'Jul', '8': 'Aug', '9': 'Sep', '10':'Oct', '11': 'Nov', '12':'Dec'}

df = (df.withColumn('month', F.col('NumMonth').cast('string'))
        .replace(months, subset=['month']))

df.show()
+--------+-----+
|NumMonth|month|
+--------+-----+
|       1|  Jan|
|       2|  Feb|
|       3|  Mar|
|       4|  Apr|
|       5|  May|
|       6|  Jun|
|       7|  Jul|
|       8|  Aug|
|       9|  Sep|
|      10|  Oct|
|      11|  Nov|
|      12|  Dec|
+--------+-----+
```

Here I had to cast `NumMonth` to string because your mapping in `months` dictionary had string keys; alternatively, you can change them to integer and avoid casting to string.

Comment: Thank you for your alternative. It already solves my code reduction issue.